# How to search a substring in string in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, string, swift4

I can't seem to find an API for String in Swift 4. Objective-C equivalent is following.

```
NSString *s = @"abcdefg";
NSString *ss = @"cde";
// just check if s contains ss
NSLog(@"%d", [s containsString:ss]);
// get range of ss in s
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange([s rangeOfString:ss]));
```

What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

I was getting this error message:

```
test.swift:1:19: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')
"abcdef".contains("cde")
```

So I didn't realize I was missing "import Foundation"...

Comment: sorry let me excuse...

I was using swift from command line and "contains" didn't build without import Foundation. Yeah that seems obvious, but I didn't realize as I was able to use String without import line.

Comment: @taichino I've added the part about importing `Foundation`. It's a requirement to use that function. This information isn't really easily available out there on the interweeb

Comment: @staticVoidMan yeah I was looking at this API doc and couldn't find contains which takes a String as a parameter. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string 

Where can I find these API's which is required to import Foundation?

Comment: When we import Foundation, Swift's `String` gets extended with  `NSString`'s capabilities. You can find those API's in [`NSString`'s Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring)

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details :)

Comment: oh wow I didn't know these API's are coming from NSString. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String` will have a

```
func contains<T>(_ other: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
```

This will be available after you import `Foundation` because it maps to `NSString`'s

```
open func contains(_ str: String) -> Bool
```

Infact importing `Foundation` extends Swift's `String` with all of `NSString`'s capabilites that you can find in it's [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring).

*Reason: Swift's `String` is **not** as evolved as `NSString` and hence it's [bridged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime/classes_bridged_to_swift_standard_library_value_types) to it, for now atleast.*

---

#### Anyways...

Swift 4 solution to check for a substring is:

```
let string = "Hello, World"
let hasSubstring = string.contains("ello")
```

Comment: @taichino No, it's okay. I had marked your question duplicate but those solutions were Swift 3 and before. Plus even I couldn't find the answer on google or get a documentation link for Swift 4 on this but anyways it was simple enough :)